# extrude a flat mesh to turn into a solid object with many faces

Tags: modeling

I have an imported SVG which I've converted to a 2D mesh.  I first dissolved many faces to make it easier to work with. Then I go into edit mode, select a face, "E" to extrude and then it pulls the face only rather than simply turning the 2D into a 3D. When I use solidify modifier all of the vertices to turn spiky.  No idea why this is happening.

[image: can't make 2D mesh into a nice 3D object]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: There might be overlapping geometry. Did you try Select All (Edit Mode) >M (Merge) > By Distance? If not, you might wanna share the file so we can take a look.

Comment: Were you in Face mode when you extruded? This looks like an extrusion of edges..

Comment: You may also want to try and fix your normals by selecting your whole mesh in edit mode and pressing Shift+N